# ionic serve stop execution when we change files

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an ionic app which is running using `ionic serve`.but when we edit any files,it stops execution.how to fix this?

```
[12:49:39]  lint finished in 8.00 s
[12:50:42]  build started ...
[12:50:42]  deeplinks update started ...
[12:50:42]  deeplinks update finished in 12 ms
[12:50:42]  template update started ...
[12:50:42]  template update finished in 15 ms
[12:50:42]  build finished in 36 ms

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:569:26)
```

**I am using application versions**

Os ubuntu 17.4

Ionic 3.19.0

Cordova 8.0.0

**>ionic info**

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.0
    Cordova Platforms  : none
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v6.9.1
    npm  : 5.4.2 
    OS   : Linux 4.10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Comment: can you show the output of `ionic info`?

Comment: @SurajRao That value is also added in the question,

Comment: I think its just a matter of updating node and npm to the current version..

Comment: That doesnt make any change @SurajRao

Comment: I found https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2922